# Create predefined data for libreoffice-calc field

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In Libreoffice-Calc, I want to create a table with some fields. For each of these fields, i would like to pre-define the allowable entries so that no other entries can be supplied. How do I do this?

Example:

```
Fields:    Fruit                                      Location
           -----                                      --------
Entries:   Apple, Orange, Pineapple, Pear...          USA, UK, EU,...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Menu Data -> Validity:

1. Select cell where the list should appear;
2. Select `Menu Data` -> `Validity`;
3. In the Validity dialog, on the `Criteria` tab, select `List`; enter the values in the `Entries` field:
   [image]
4. Optionally: Enter help information on the `Input Help` / `Error Alert` tabs;
5. That's it. The result will look as follows (with `Input Help` defined):
   [image]

Comment: Thanks. Just what i needed.